# How to execute Javascript from external HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a button that executes the code

`$('#main').load('welcome.html');`

and in `welcome.html` I have a button that executes the code

`$('#main').load('otherpage.html');`

the Javascript isn't executed, regardless of whether that function is on the parent file's HTML code or the child's.

How can I get a Javascript function to work from externally loaded HTML files?

**EDIT**
Here's a bit more of a sample...

Homepage:

```
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>

<script>
    document.onLoad(){
        $('#main').load('welcome.html');
    }

    function show(file){
        $('#main').load(file+'.html');
    }
</script>
```

`welcome.html` page:

```
<a href="javascript:show(test)">Test</a>
```

...however when the Test button is clicked, `test.html` is not loaded into the Main div.

**EDIT 2**

Here is what the current state is and what the issue is - exactly.

[I've uploaded the bones of the code to PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/XAjbFFnk).

When the 'grid' button is clicked, the content changes and the footer changes.

However, the footer, which has URLs based on Javascript, comes up with the error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

...when trying to access the `1i.html` page.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `script` tag?

Comment: I do... these functions are within `script` tags. The rest of my Javascript works, I'm just trying to make a one-page site with external pages loaded that also contain Javascript. The home page works, the others don't when they are loaded.

Comment: do you have items with ID of "main" on both pages? Do you have a more complete sample we can refer to?

Comment: Well when you try to use the JavaScript function make sure it is below the `#main` tag.

Comment: Post a code example, please.

Comment: Updated the code example... still having no luck.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between `test` the variable and `'test'` the string:

```
<a href="javascript:show(test)">Test</a>
```

Probably should be:

```
<a href="javascript:void show('test')">Test</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - please see updated question for a more specific breakdown of the issue!

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that when loading script into page via AJAX that the main page has already gone through `document.ready` . Thus, any code you load will fire immediately.

If the code you load precedes the html it references, it will not find that html when it fires.

Placing the code after the html in remote page will resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Check [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Maybe your eventhandler is wrong. When you import new markup via load() or ajax(), you have to initialize the handlers from new document. The easiest way is using jQuery.on or jQuery.live() instead of jQuery.click().

```
$('MYBUTTON').live('click', function(){
    $('#main').load('your_url.html')
})
```

or use the callbackfunction to (re-)initialize the buttons event.

A better solution is this: Just add the target_url to buttons rel attribute...

```
<button rel="YOUR_URL.html">Open Page</button>

$('button[rel]').live('click', function(){
    $('#main').load($(this).attr('rel'));
})
```